# In Perforce visual client how to link the depot view with the workspace view

Tags: p4v

so that when we move to a particular file in one view, it automatically navigates to the mapped file in the other view? I had used this before but forgot now how, and there is no menu item anywhere in p4v for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the workspace. In the depot view, right-click and then select "Restrict view -> Restrict to workspace view"
Hope this helps.